# For the Android Spotify API, how do I get the album artowrk image into an imageView? I've tried using Track but no good

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, spotify

I've tried using Track to grab the album artwork but still nothing is displaying. I'm not sure would Picasso be something that could help - I tried it but again, no luck.

```
mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi().subscribeToPlayerState().setEventCallback(playerState -> {
                    final Track track = playerState.track;
                    if (track != null) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", track.name + " by " + track.artist.name);
                        album_artwork.setImageResource(track.imageUri.hashCode());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting the artwork image url. verify url first if image url is valid or not. Then by using Picasso all you need to do is:

`Picasso.get().load(track.imageUri).into(album_artwork);`

Please check Spotify official android sample. https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/tree/master/app-remote-sample

Comment: You got me on the right track with the above answer so thanks. I ended up using a substring of the image URI: Picasso.get().load("https://i.scdn.co/image/"+ track.imageUri.toString().substring(22, track.imageUri.toString().length() - 2)).into(album_artwork); - It works - but surely there's a better way to grab the artwork URL than manually forming it.

Comment: Please check Spotify official android sample.  https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/tree/master/app-remote-sample

Comment: Please accept answer if it solved your problem so that it may helps others too.Thanks

Comment: Perfect, that link shows exactly what's required. Thank you!